# Data tag parsing failed: Expected ']' but got '<EOF>' at: ...:307,Slot:0b},{ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}<--[HERE]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Alright, so I'm trying to set up a command to give me a sword with 7 attack damage and an attack speed of 100 so that it has no recharge. The command I'm entering goes as follows:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Sword",Lore:["Smexy"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackSpeed",Name:"generic.attackSpeed",Amount:100,Operation:1,UUIDMost:307,UUIDLeast:307,Slot:0b},{ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}}
```

And everytime I do the command it comes up with this:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Expected ']' but got '<EOF>' at: ...:307,Slot:0b},{ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}<--[HERE]
```

Comment: Did you copy that command from somewhere? Try typing it manually, it seems like you have an invisible character in there.

Comment: I would also recommend using https://mcstacker.net/ for this in the future. Makes everything a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft commands expect every certain symbols to be paired with each other. In particular, every `[` or `{` should be matched with a `]` or `}`, respectively. These symbols work similarly to parenthesis in Mathematics, they indicate that their contents should be considered as a single item. So the error message `Expected ']' but got '<EOF>'` means that your command had a `[` symbol, but Minecraft couldn't find a `]` to go with it.

In your particular case, Minecraft couldn't find a `]` to go with the `[` found right after `AttributeModifiers:`. So you should add a `]` after all the attributes; specifically, between the last two `}` characters. This results in the following command, which executes successfully:

> /give @p diamond_sword 1 0
>   {display:{Name:"Sword",Lore:["Smexy"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackSpeed",Name:"generic.attackSpeed",Amount:100,Operation:1,UUIDMost:307,UUIDLeast:307,Slot:0b},{ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}]}

Comment: This didn't work. It got rid of the error message but it didn't give the sword any level of sharpness

Comment: The enchantment tag doesn't belong inside the attribute modifiers. It has to be only inside the outer most curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Lets simplify your command by removing all lot of data.

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{...},AttributeModifiers:[{...},{ench:[{...}]}}
```

AttributeModifiers has no `]` before the enchantment section.  The enchantment section is contained in curly brackets and should not be.  This would give us:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{...},AttributeModifiers:[{...}],ench:[{...}]}
```

The last thing, `Slot:0b` does not work with attribute modifiers to my knowledge.  If you are wanting it to be in the main hand, the proper slot name is `"mainhand"`

Which would give us a final command of:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Sword",Lore:["Smexy"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackSpeed",Name:"generic.attackSpeed",Amount:100,Operation:1,UUIDMost:307,UUIDLeast:307,Slot:"mainhand"}],ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}
```

Which gives us this guy:
[image: Sword]